# Why are 32-bit processes started under 64-bit processes in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

When I run a 32-bit program in Windows 7 64-bit often times a 64-bit process is started with a 32-bit process underneath it. For instance, if I start iexplorer.exe (Internet Explorer) from C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer it starts a 64-bit process with a 32-bit process underneath it.

[image: a]

This can be seen in Process Explorer as well as Task Manager.

[image: b]

Why is this? What's going on here? Also, if I go to C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer and start iexplorer.exe from there, again, both a 64-bit and a 32-bit process is started. The executable in this folder is supposed to start a 64-bit version of the program.

Comment: That's by design to ensure 32-bit add-ons (e.g. Browser Helper Objects (BHOs), toolbars, and ActiveX controls) work as expected. The main manager process always matches the operating system bitness, but tabs can be either 32-bit or 64-bit processes. If you want IE to be fully 64-bit you can enable the [Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If the 64bit application needs (or thinks it may need) to interface with 32bit applications, modules, or processes, it'll spawn a 32bit process to manage that interaction.

In the case of IE, as was mentioned in @and31415's comment, it needs to interact with add-ons (such as Flash, ActiveX etc.) as well as other applications that may be needed, based upon the content you browse).

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer (starting with version 7 on Windows Vista), as well as Chrome, and Firefox, use separate processes for each tab. Internet Explorer termed this *"Protected Mode"*.

You have your main browser process, that handles the main frame UI, as well as all network and disk access. Each tab is then run in a separate **Low Integrity Level** process (which you can see in Process Explorer).

- iexplore.exe *(Medium Mandatory Integrity Level)*

  - iexplore.exe *(Low Mandatatory Integrity Level)*
  - iexplore.exe *(Low Mandatatory Integrity Level)*
  - iexplore.exe *(Low Mandatatory Integrity Level)*

Processes marked with **Low** integrity level are [very limited in what they can do.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

That is why you see multiple processes of iexplore, chrome, and firefox.